# MySQL select query, selecting where from a column generated on-the-fly

Tags: sql, mysql, select, where-clause

I have a (my)SQL question. If I have a table, let's say called Cars with various columns, two of which are INT which I want to add together, one called backwheels and the other called frontwheels.

I can do this query to add them together when I select

`select (backwheels+frontwheels) as totalwheels from Cars;`

which works fine, but when I try and do a select where on that totalwheels column, I get an error

`select (backwheels+frontwheels) as totalwheels from Cars where totalwheels=4;`

the error I get back:

> Unknown column 'totalwheels' in 'where
>   clause'

Is it possible to somehow select from a column which doesn't really exist like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
select (backwheels+frontwheels) as totalwheels from Cars
where (backwheels+frontwheels)=4;
```

OR:

```
SELECT * from 
(select c.*, (backwheels+frontwheels) as totalwheels from Cars)
where totalwheels=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because your table doesn't have a column "totalwheels" and your where clause is trying to run a condition on a column that doesn't exist.

You can try using -

```
select (backwheels+frontwheels) as totalwheels from Cars where (backwheels+frontwheels)=4;
```

Answer (score -2):

Better try with Alias:

```
select (c.backwheels+c.frontwheels) as totalwheels from Cars as c where totalwheels=4;
```